# The use of the word "ok"

Tags: meaning

Does adding the word "ok" to the end of a statement imply a choice instead of a command or order?  Example:  "Wash the dishes now". as opposed to "Wash the dishes now, ok?"  Does this weaken your statement?

Comment: It's a **sarcastic** (or perhaps rhetoric) **question** - actually a command.

Comment: (Note that you could say it "and really mean it". But then anything sarcastic or rhetoric, you could "actually mean".)

Comment: And note that as you say **yes**, in some ways this has become a "gentler" way of giving the command. It's rather like saying "how's that sound to you? do we all agree?"; so, when you say those things, in fact the person has to do them anyway :) but it "gives the feel" that you're being included in the decision-making process. So - as you suggest - somewhat surprisingly ", OK?" has in practice been rather **softened** lately. Note for example: "Wash the dishes. You got a problem with that?" would be a very mean way to say it. Note that you can substitute "Wash the dishes, alright?" also.

Comment: It has a slightly threatening tone about it, even without the ok. But that makes it worse.

Answer (score 3):

If my spouse says:

*"Please wash the dishes now."*

She expects action and no verbal reply at all.

If she says:

*"Please wash the dishes now, OK?"*

She expects both a response and action.

*(of course this my be spouse-English as opposed to general English)*

Comment: +1 - You can think of it acting as a communications protocol marker. It effectively says, "You must acknowledge this statement I just made, and I will synchronously sit here and wait for you to do so". Without it, the other party might later claim they didn't hear the previous sentence.

Comment: (note that most spouses use a fairly sophisticated algorithm that will issue retries of the original request if it isn't acked with an "OK" in a reasonable amount of time. A negative acknowledgement is generally not considered the end of the communication, but rather initiates the household chore negotiation protocol)

Answer (score 1):

By adding in the okay at the end, you are transforming the sentence from a command to a question. When you say, "Wash the dishes now", you are expecting the other to wash the dishes. If the other person objects, the two of you would be in disagreement. However, when you say, "Wash the dishes now, okay?", you are saying, "I'd like you to wash the dishes now. Is that okay?", leaving room for the other person's response and further discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Consider these statements where *OK* is replaced by question tags:

> You would wash the dishes, wouldn't you?

Same idea is conveyed in tone of command or request based on the speaker's intonation.

> You will remind me about grampa, won't you?

Politely making a request.